# Java EE, EntitiManager Query, SELECT JOINED entities

Tags: jpa, join, jakarta-ee, entity

This is what I have (of course in a sintetic form)

```
@Entity
public class Event {
    @Id
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private Set<ScheduledEvents> scheduledEvents

}

@Entity
public class ScheduledEvents {
    @Id
    private int id;
    private Date date;

}
```

If I want to retrive all events... well, it's pretty Easy:

```
List<Event> events = em.getResultList("SELECT e FROM Event e");
```

Now, what I would like to do.. is to retrive all Events, which are scheduled (ScheduledEvents) in the future (with scheduleEvents.date >= TODAY). I've produced something like this... but of course it doesn't work!

```
List<Event> events = em.getResultList("SELECT e FROM Event e JOIN se WHERE se.date>?1", new Date());
```

Any help?

Comment: Mauro.
What exactly don't work? You are getting an exception or wrong results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT e FROM Event e JOIN e.scheduledEvents se WHERE se.date > ?1
```

should do the trick. You will get the same event several times if it's schedules at several future dates, though. Use `select distinct e...` to get each event once